# Python How to convert a file of open XML format to MS ole format using python?

Tags: python, excel, ms-office

I want to convert open XML format files like docx, xlsx, ppsx to MS OLE format like doc, xls, pps using python. Is there any library to do so? I have to run the python code on my linux server where no Microsoft office is installed. So it it possible to do it with python or is it possible to do it using code?

Answer (score 0):

Check out [pyoo](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyoo)
It's some binding to OpenOffice / LibreOffice.

> The library can be used for generating documents in various formats – including Microsoft Excel 97 (.xls), Microsoft Excel 2007 (.xlsx) and PDF.

Hope this disadvantage isn't huge problem:

> On the other hand it needs a running process of a office suite application which is significant overhead.